# Google Maps Geocode doesn't return country

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

I need a reliable method to get the **city**, **state** and **country** **place_id** from latitude and longitude.

I'm trying by using Google Maps geocode, but the problem is that some coordinates don't return the administrative_level_1 (state) or the country.

Take this GET request for instance:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-25.4364413,-49.2839333&result_type=country&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

It returns:

```
{
    "results": [],
    "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Did you know a way to get this results?

Comment: If I [remove the `result_type=country` from the request, the country is there](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-25.4364413,-49.2839333&key=AIzaSyAqVFNSpmGM2t_FKecIz5uZgHdXrOKraPg)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't return the place_id, you can check this [request for instance](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.0522,118.2437&result_type=country&key=AIzaSyAqVFNSpmGM2t_FKecIz5uZgHdXrOKraPg), is the same format, but in this case, it returns the country place_id

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug and it was reported in Google issue tracker in November 2016. Please have a look at bug report and feel free to star it to add your vote.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829979

I've already added a link to this question in the bug. You can also check workarounds suggested by users in bug comments.

For example, there is following suggestion

> I found a workaround:
>   if I do not get a country back, I will do a second reverse geocoding with the coordinates of the highest result I got. 
>   Most of the times these coordinates will be in an area, where I can get the country.
>
> This is not ideal, but it works for the cases I found.

I believe you might also be interested in the feature request 'Add place_id in each address_components':

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827596

Feel free to star it as well.