# Missing country component in geocode API result

Tags: google-geocoder

I want to get place_ids of hierarchical result, following the answer in [Hierarchical & translated results of a placeId using Google Places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590171/hierarchical-translated-results-of-a-placeid-using-google-places)

Everything goes fine at first, but in this request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-34.63289,116.12236&key=MY_KEY&language=en&result_type=country|administrative_area_level_1|administrative_area_level_2|locality

country component is missing.

How can I fix this?

Comment: go into your  developer console in credential there is an option call **REGENERATE KEY** ,regenerate key and then put it in your code.this will work.

Comment: This is quite an old bug reported in Google issue tracker. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46043732/5140781